# Mathematica + Calibre?

Tags: calibre

The latest version of Calibre (August 2015) does a superb job converting doc.x files to Epubs. You get a perfect table of contents and better still, your  text wraps around frames. Unfortunately, Calibre does not 'see' the equations, charts, and animations native to Mathematica 10. Is there any hope? Does anyone out there know of a work around?

Comment: Have you brought up your findings with Kovid Goyal? Or the user community? http://calibre-ebook.com/get-involved

Comment: Kovid Goyal told me he's not interested.

Comment: That's unfortunate.

Comment: Can you export your MS Word to RTF, then have Calibre convert the RTF to epub (rather than docx).

Comment: The epub is just a bunch of HTML - how would Mathematica display in an HTML page?  Is it using proprietary fonts?  Looking at Wolfram's site, I can't actually see anything that looks like it even works on their own website.